# Light catcher object lit via light path node of fire fluid rendering odd shadow in cycles render

Tags: rendering, fire

I've got a scene setup like this with a fire fluid casting illumination via a light path shader node onto the rear plane geometry, the plane is perpendicular to the render camera which is facing it directly (on the LHS of the screenshot):

[image]

The viewport shader preview shows the fire lighting the plane correctly, when I render it in cycles however there is an odd shadow artifact as if there is an invisible plane in the centre horizontal casting a shadow, these are a few screenshots from the animation of the lighting, the fire moves "above and below this invisible shadow plane in Z" throughout:

[image]

Questions:

1. What is causing this? I've tried tilting the plane slighting in X in both directions and this invisible shadow plane is still there.
2. Something else related to this, in Maya there is a global shadow settings option in the render settings where you can set resolution of shadow maps, sampling etc to sort out shadow quality, I cannot see such an option in blender unless it is under each light object property, in this case there is no light as the light is coming from the fluid simulation. So how do I control the shadow quality which I believe can also be related to this issue?

Comment: have you checked the outliner for any plane that's hidden in the viewport?

Comment: Yes, I thought I did. I just went back to it this morning and sure enough there was one there hidden in viewport but rendering. On a following note, can you help with query two above (how to control shadow quality)? After the fire light pass, I'm planning on using the same plane to act as a shadow catcher object which I haven't yet done in Blender.

Comment: What render engine does Maya use? I do know that you can set the resolution of shadow maps in Eevee. It's a drop-down menu in shadow section of render properties. But atleast in Cycles, since everything is pathtraced, I don't understand why you would have a resolution control. Maybe the render engine in Maya is a rasterization engine like Eevee or it's a hybrid. But never used Maya so idk.

Comment: The default software renderer as you say is rasterised type I believe, you can set shadow map resolutions, bake them and have more overall control on the shadow look be it soft, spread out or sharp, Mental Ray which I think has now been superseeded by Arnold was ray traced type but you had control over the sampling level much like the general noise level in cycles.

Comment: The shadow maps in raster engines are in simplified sense just an image slapped over everything else. It is the resolution of this image that you can set. But in pathtraced the everything is actual light ray calculation stuff. So there is actually no way to have a control over shadows the way you do in raster engines(As far as I know). But please keep in mind that if a raster engine has ray tracing options, then that's different and you still have control over your shadow maps(Again, as far as I know)